# Convert duplicated columns to multiple entries in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
Date,First,First,Second,Second
2022-01-01,one,two,three,four
2022-01-02,five,six,seven,eight
```

How can I convert a table like the above, with many of the same number of columns of the same title ('First' is a column twice, and 'Second' is a column twice) into a table like the below where each duplicated column becomes part of a new row with a duplicated independent variable:

```
Date,First,Second
2022-01-01,one,three
2022-01-01,two,four
2022-01-02,five,seven
2022-01-02,six,eight
```

Answer (score 0):

**One of the possible solutions:**

You can use formula and auto AutFill option.
Suppose We have a table like you in Sheet1:

```
Date,First,First,Second,Second
2022-01-01,one,two,three,four
2022-01-02,five,six,seven,eight
```

Now, I use Sheet2 with table like:

```
Date, First, Second
```

In Cell A2, B2, C2 using `Indirect`, `IF`, `ISEVEN`, `ROW` and `Rounddown` with AutoFill to create desired table:

In Cell `A2` Write:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)+1)
```

In Cell `B2`:

```
=INDIRECT(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),"Sheet1!B"&ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)+1,""Sheet1!C"&ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)+1"))
```

And Finally in Cell `C2`:

```
=INDIRECT(IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),"Sheet1!D"&ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)+1,""Sheet1!E"&ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)+1"))
```

Now, you can use AutoFill Option, select A2 to C2 and drag it to desired cell. Final Result is:

```
Date,First,Second
2022-01-01,one,three
2022-01-01,two,four
2022-01-02,five,seven
2022-01-02,six,eight
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Excel Power Query.

First import your data into Power Query via Data tab > Get & Transform Data group > From Table/Range.

Then go to Home tab > Transform group > Group By, choose "**Advanced**" option, group data by: Date, First and Second. Choose to get "**All Rows**". On my Sample, I named the new column as "Test", then we will get a column with text of "Table".

[image]

Click the icon besides with header "Test". Select: Date, First2 and Second3 to expand.

[image]

Go to left Queries column, copy the "Table1" and copy it, we will get a same query called "Table1(2)".

In Table1, we just keep columns of Date, First and Second.

[image]

In Table1(2), we just keep columns of Test.Date, Test.First2 and Test.Second3.

[image]

**But we need to modify headers to be the same as headers Table1.**

Go to Home tab > Combine group > Append Queries > Append Queries as a new, then append these 2 tables into one.

[image]